# How can I stretch a bone's tail to another bone or empty with a constraint?

Tags: armature, constraints

A want the second bone's tail to stretch to the third's head.

I have tried to use the Stretch To constraint but then I would need the target to be at the tail at start.

Is there a way to force the tail position to the thirds head?

[image]

It's a bit confusing... The bone has only one position in pose mode, but in edit mode it has two positions (head and tail). So when using the stretch to constraint all it can do is to scale the bone. What I really want is to adjust the length of the bone but that attribute doesn't makes sens in pose mode.

The end goal of this is to create joins aligned to other objects and then Apply Pose As Rest Pose.

I'm starting to think it wasn't a good idea.

[Edit]
There is apparently no way of doing this using bone constraints only.
It could be done with an intermediate object constraint but it would be a complicated and not a useful solution.

Comment: Have you tried the Head/Tail Slider in the Bone Constraint Properties? It is right under the Target bone's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that there is some confusion between pose mode and edit mode: if your end goal is to apply pose as rest pose, it means that you want to have your rig modified in edit mode: this is the same result as editing in edit mode: so go to edit mode, select the head of the third bone, press Shift S "cursor to selected", then select the tail of the second bone, press Shift S "Selection to cursor". Then you'll have to choose if the third bone is connected and parented to the second or not (by now they only share the same location in one joint): if you want that select the third, shift select the second, press Ctrl P and choose "connected".

Comment: There is no confusion over edit vs pose. The difference is just unintuitive for me. I wanted to use constraints to get my bones into place and then apply pose and remove the constraints. It's not uncommon to do this and it works well in Maya, but Maya uses Joints instead of bone which is a more primitive concept and also doesn't have a pose mode. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Bone Head/Tail Silder]

The Stretch to Constraint has a Head/Tail Slider that allows target any point between the Head and Tail of the target bone.

[image: Snap to Head]

If you want to align the positions perfectly, simply use the 3D-Cursor place it on the target head and then snap the other bone's tail to its position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think you got my question quite right though. What I needed was to force the tail go to the head. I don't think there actually is a way to do this with constrains.

Comment: You are, I still do not get it. The constraint holder's tail does go to the head of the target bone. I think you need to word your question differently, other than that, I cannot see what other outcome you want to achieve.

Comment: What is there to not get? The tail should be at the position of the head... adjusting the Rest Length does not get the Tail to be att the precise position of the Head and is not automatically computed.

Comment: Put the 3D-Cursor on the head and snap the tail of the other bone to it, then.